# ResultSet is empty even though the query works

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I have the following code:

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE ((EVENT_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (EVENT_TIME BETWEEN ? AND ?))");
connection = SQLiteWrapper.getConnection();
            try (PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString()))
            {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar copy = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
                copy.set(1900, 0, 1);
                SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String formattedStartDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                String formattedStartTime = timeFormat.format(copy.getTime());
                copy.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
                calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
                String formattedEndDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                String formattedEndTime = timeFormat.format(copy.getTime());
                pst.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedStartDate));
                pst.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedEndDate));
                pst.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf(formattedStartTime));
                pst.setTimestamp(4, Timestamp.valueOf(formattedEndTime));
```

Later on, I'm executing the prepared statement like so: `ResultSet set = pst.executeQuery()`.

And for some unknown reason, this query doesn't select anything, when it actually should - It's working if I execute it in the SQLite's query editor.

Is there's a reason why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you print out the values of all `formattedStartTime` and `formattedEndTime` as I don't think the value is what you think it is. Are you aware that you can create a `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` from a `Calendar` without applying string conversion.

Comment: Can you try to hard code the values in you query and run the application. Just check if it returns data, if it does, then maybe we can debug further.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've debugged my code before I posted this, and yes, the values are exactly what I need them to be.
However, about the 2nd thing you said - I don't remember where I read it, but I read that the only acceptable format for the setDate method is yyyy-MM-dd, which isn't the default format of the Calendar. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TimorGruber Yes, but it would be helpful for **us** to know which values you use. `java.sql.Date` doesn't have a time format. You can create a `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` from a millisecond value, which can be obtained from `Calendar` (through `getTimeInMillis`). It would also be helpful to know the datatypes of `EVENT_DATE` and `EVENT_TIME` (the names suggest `DATE` and `TIME`, in which case use of `Timestamp` is incorrect)

Comment: @Logan I've checked it, and it appears that the hard coded query actually works and I do get what I wanted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In fact, the datatypes are date and datetime, since SQLite doesn't have a Time datatype (Or at least not one that I'm aware of). About the millis - it seems I can't get it right cause I get thrown with ClassCastException, so can you please demonstrate the correct use?

Comment: `new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis())` and similar for `java.sql.Date`. If you use datetime, why do you have a separate `event_date` column? And also are you sure the `EVENT_TIME` column has date 1900-01-01 (and not simply the same date as `EVENT_DATE`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I'm sure. I made it this way so I could compare the time with the BETWEEN statement, if you have another idea I would love to hear it. I keep the EVENT_DATE and EVENT_TIME in separate columns because they're not related although it seems so at first glance. I keep in the Events Table also the index of days in a week which the event can occur on, thus I need a separate EVENT_TIME column. Maybe this design is wrong and separating the days and time to different tables will work, but this same design worked perfectly in C#.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've also tried to store the java.sql.Date and Timestamp objects using the milliseconds, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Well, it seems that I've solved it!
1st of all, I've changed the structure of the db so it will be more friendly to work on, but then, I've noticed that in one of my tables, not related to this topic, the date was saved in milliseconds, and at that moment I finally realized that JDBC works only in this format, unlike C# for example. It converts whatever format you have, to milliseconds, and that's why my query returned no results in the java program.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel for your time and help, I couldn't manage without it!

Comment: And since stack overflow doesn't let me tag two people at once, I have to comment again to thanks @Logan as well for your help!